# Send mail with gmail and R

Tags: r, email, sendmailr

I am simply trying to send an email with R through my gmail account using the mailR package but it does not seem to work.

I get this error:

> ```
> Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
>   org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : aspmx.l.google.com:25
> ```

Below is the code with anonymized gmail adresses.

```
install.packages("mailR")
library(mailR)
sender <- "sender@gmail.com"  # Replace with a valid address
    recipients <- c("receiver1@gmail.com")  # Replace with one or more valid addresses
    email <- send.mail(from = sender,
                       to = recipients,
                       subject="Subject of the email",
                       body = "Body of the email",
                       smtp = list(host.name = "aspmx.l.google.com", port = 25),
                       authenticate = FALSE,
                       send = FALSE)


    email$send() # execute to send email
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the server right?  Perhaps off topic, but can you get it working directly from Java?

Comment: Hi, I am not able to answer your questions, how can I check all this? Are you asking if the host name is the correct one?

Comment: Yes, I am asking if you are certain about the host name.  As the R library appears to be running Java under the hood, I also asked whether you have tried connecting directly via Java.

Comment: I had also tried a different host name (with gmail in it) but didnt work either. As for Java I really just know R...

Comment: I don't know this API well enough to be of much use to you.  I can only recommend that you take apart your call and try to see if each piece is working correctly.  Checking that domain some how would be a good step in that direction.

Comment: You can answer your own question below.

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to make it work ! You have to authorize the app on Google. This link really helped me: https://medium.com/airbnb-engineering/using-googlesheets-and-mailr-packages-in-r-to-automate-reporting-c09579e0377f